# Ada: Write to File Multiple Times

Tags: file, output, ada

In Ada, can you open, write to, close, then reopen, write to, and close a txt file without it being overwritten? Like continue from where it last left off?
Thanks!

Comment: is "append" the word you're looking for? There is an "append_file" mode you can supply to the mode parameter in the open call...

Comment: exactly @BrianDrummond

Comment: Sweet! Now the problem is that everytime I write to the file again, it goes to the next line. Anyway to prevent that? @BrianDrummond

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  If you look in section A.10.1 in the reference manual, you can see that the package `Ada.Text_IO` includes the declaration:

```
type File_Mode is (In_File, Out_File, Append_File);
```

`Append_File` is the mode you are looking for.

A.10.2(3) in the reference manual requires that you get a new line, when you close a file:

> For the procedure `Close`: If the file has the current mode `Out_File` or `Append_File`, has the effect of calling `New_Page`, unless the current page is already terminated; then outputs a file terminator.

... where A.10.5(16) explains what `New_Page` does:

> Operates on a file of mode `Out_File` or `Append_File`. Outputs a line terminator if the current line is not terminated, or if the current page is empty (that is, if the current column and line numbers are both equal to one). Then outputs a page terminator, which terminates the current page. Adds one to the current page number and sets the current column and line numbers to one.

If you want more detailed control over what ends up in a file, you should use one of the other I/O packages.